# Shorewall: Block repeatedly failling ips on port 22

Tags: security, fedora, shorewall

I am on Fedora 21, and port 22 is open for ssh connections.

I am using key-based authentication with password and root logins disabled.

My logs are flooded with messages like the ones appended at the end of the post.

I am using shorewall, is there a native way to blacklist an IP for 2 days after failing 3 times to connect?

If not, how would a regex for fail2ban look like?

```
$ journalctl -u sshd

Jun 06 10:16:01 fedora sshd[27659]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:01 fedora sshd[27659]: error: Received disconnect from 195.154.56.58: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:02 fedora sshd[27661]: Invalid user support from 195.154.56.58
Jun 06 10:16:02 fedora sshd[27661]: input_userauth_request: invalid user support [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:02 fedora sshd[27661]: error: Received disconnect from 195.154.56.58: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:14 fedora sshd[27663]: Invalid user ubnt from 195.154.56.58
Jun 06 10:16:14 fedora sshd[27663]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubnt [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:14 fedora sshd[27663]: error: Received disconnect from 195.154.56.58: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:18 fedora sshd[27665]: error: Received disconnect from 195.154.56.58: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:21 fedora sshd[27668]: Invalid user user from 195.154.56.58
Jun 06 10:16:21 fedora sshd[27668]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:21 fedora sshd[27668]: error: Received disconnect from 195.154.56.58: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Jun 06 10:16:32 fedora sshd[27670]: Did not receive identification string from 195.154.56.58
Jun 06 11:25:38 fedora sshd[27832]: Did not receive identification string from 92.27.215.72
Jun 06 11:26:52 fedora sshd[27836]: Invalid user usuario from 92.27.215.72
Jun 06 11:26:52 fedora sshd[27836]: input_userauth_request: invalid user usuario [preauth]
Jun 06 11:26:52 fedora sshd[27836]: Connection closed by 92.27.215.72 [preauth]
Jun 06 11:40:39 fedora sshd[27865]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 62-210-7-55.rev.poneytelecom.eu [62.210.7.55] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jun 06 11:40:39 fedora sshd[27865]: Invalid user admin from 62.210.7.55
Jun 06 11:40:39 fedora sshd[27865]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Jun 06 11:40:39 fedora sshd[27865]: error: Received disconnect from 62.210.7.55: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
Jun 06 11:40:44 fedora sshd[27867]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 62-210-7-55.rev.poneytelecom.eu [62.210.7.55] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jun 06 11:40:44 fedora sshd[27867]: Invalid user support from 62.210.7.55
Jun 06 11:40:44 fedora sshd[27867]: input_userauth_request: invalid user support [preauth]
```

Comment: You mean other than fail2ban?

Comment: Fail2ban needs an extra regex and ```backend = systemd``` to work well with journalctl. I am not good with regex and I would appreciate some help, given that shorewall cannot monitor this activity by itself.

Comment: Huh? Fail2ban already includes perfectly usable regexes for ssh log entries, and works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The following config seems to be working with fail2ban out of the box and doing the desired job.

My original config was misconfigured since I wrote `[DEFAULT]` as `[default]`.

```
$ cat /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
[DEFAULT]
bantime = 172800 
findtime=3600
maxretry = 3
backend = systemd
action = shorewall

[sshd]
enabled = true

[sshd-ddos]
enabled = true
```